# Legal aspects of Java specification implementations in other programming languages

Tags: java, legal, api, specifications, implementations

I am planning to implement an official Java specification in a different programming language. Would this be a copyright violation?

Hypothetical examples:

- a [**JMX**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-135104.html) "wrapper" library for C++ which can control a Java application over JMX, and uses similar concepts and class/method names as the Java implementation
- a [**JavaMail**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail-138606.html) API and implementations (for different .Net network libraries) for C#

Comment: You might want to check out http://www.ikvm.net/

Answer (score 4):

Implementing to APIs and the like probably isn't a copyright violation in the USA.  If you need actual legal advice, find a lawyer of the proper specialty in the jurisdiction you're in.  It'll be a lot cheaper than defending a lawsuit if you guess wrong.

Please note that asking legal advice on an international forum primarily composed of non-lawyers is not completely reliable, particularly when you neglect to tell us where you live.  Laws do vary from country to country, even relatively consistent ones like copyright.

Comment: Yes, find an expert on the subject.